# How can I access child members of a tabNavigator created via ActionScript at run time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am creating a tabNavigator object in mxml.

TabNavigator  contains  navigatorContent objects.

Each NavigatorContent further contains multiple hGroups with three radio buttons in it.

All these elements are populated in the tabNavigator via actionScript code dynamically.

I need to select the second radio button within an hgroup, but am not sure how to do this.

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabNav" height="100" width="500" creationComplete="init();" creationPolicy="all"> 
</mx:TabNavigator> 

private function init():void
{
    for(var i:int=0;i<=int(arrColl_items[arrColl_items.length - 1][1]);
    i++)
    {
        //after reading from xml var navContent:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
        for (var j:int=0;j<arrColl_items.length;j++)
        {
            if(arrColl_items[j][1] == i)
            {
                var hgrp:HGroup = new HGroup();
                hgrp.id = String(arrColl_items[j][0]);
                var rdBut1:RadioButton=new RadioButton();
                hgrp.addElement(rdBut1);
                rdBut1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setrdBut1);
                var rdBut2:RadioButton=new RadioButton();
                hgrp.addElement(rdBut2);
                rdBut2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setrdBut2);
                var rdBut3:RadioButton=new RadioButton();
                hgrp.addElement(rdBut3);
                rdBut3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setrdBut3);
            }
        }
        navContent.addElement(hgrp);
        tabNav.addChildAt(navContent,i);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help out on this?

Regards

Aparna

Answer (score 0):

you did not post the data structure, i hope i got it right. The following demo creates and populates a TabNavigator with three NavigatorContent instances containing series of RadioButtons that can be selected using the method 'getHGroupById'.
I am sure it is possible to realize something like this using Bindable Data and ItemRenderes, probably the better solution.
*Nicholas

The Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:TabNavigator id="tabNav" height="300" width="300" creationComplete="__init();" creationPolicy="all"> 
    </mx:TabNavigator> 
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;          
            import spark.components.NavigatorContent;
            import spark.components.VGroup;

            /**
             * The Data Structure, as I understood it
             * perhaps you have to adapt the code if
             * this does not match your desired structure
             * or hierarchy
             * */
            private var arrColl_items:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
                [
                    new ArrayCollection(                
                        // 1st NavigatorContent
                        [
                            {id:"0",label:"HGroup_1.1"},
                            {id:"1",label:"HGroup_1.2"}
                        ]
                    ),
                    new ArrayCollection(                        
                        // 2nd NavigatorContent
                        [
                            {id:"2",label:"HGroup_2.1"},
                            {id:"3",label:"HGroup_2.2"},
                            {id:"4",label:"HGroup_2.3"}
                        ]
                    ),
                    new ArrayCollection(
                        // 3rd NavigatorContent
                        [
                            {id:"5",label:"HGroup_3.2"},
                            {id:"6",label:"HGroup_3.3"},
                            {id:"7",label:"HGroup_3.4"},
                            {id:"8",label:"HGroup_3.5"},
                            {id:"9",label:"HGroup_3.5"}
                        ]
                    )

                ]
            );

            /**
             * Invoked on creationComplete
             * */
            private function __init():void
            {
                // lets add some navigatorContent
                for(var i:int=0;i<arrColl_items.length;i++){
                    // create the navigatorContent
                    var navContent:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();                   
                    navContent.label = "navContent_"+i;

                    // add a VGroup
                    var vgrp:VGroup = new VGroup();
                    vgrp.id = "vGroup";

                    // and now we add custom HGroup Components called MyHGroup  
                    for (var j:int=0;j<arrColl_items[i].length;j++)
                    {
                        var hgrp:MyHGroup = new MyHGroup();
                        hgrp.id = arrColl_items[i][j].id;
                        hgrp.label.text = arrColl_items[i][j].label;                        
                        vgrp.addElement(hgrp);
                    }                   
                    navContent.addElement(vgrp);
                    tabNav.addElementAt(navContent,i);
                }

                // Accessing the radioButtons is now possible
                // using the getHGroupById Method
                getHGroupById("0").rb1.selected = true;
                getHGroupById("1").rb2.selected = true;
                getHGroupById("3").rb3.selected = true;
                getHGroupById("7").rb1.selected = true;

                // I added a RadioGroup within MyHGroup, lets read the selectedValue
                trace(getHGroupById("0").rbGroup.selectedValue);
            }


            /**
             * getHGroupById
             * Method that runs through the Data Structure
             * and returns a MyHGroup Class with the given id
             * @param $id:String The id of the MyHGroup Class you want to fetch
             * @return MyHGroup or null if non existent
             * 
             * */
            public function getHGroupById($id:String):MyHGroup{
                // running through the NavigatorContent Instances
                for(var i:uint=0; i<tabNav.numElements; i++){
                    var navContent:NavigatorContent = NavigatorContent(tabNav.getElementAt(i));                 
                    // running through the HGroups within a VGroup
                    for(var j:uint=0; j<VGroup(navContent.getElementAt(0)).numElements; j++){                       
                        var hgrp:MyHGroup = VGroup(navContent.getElementAt(0)).getElementAt(j) as MyHGroup;                     
                        if(hgrp.id==$id)return hgrp;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
</s:Application>
```

Finally the MyHGroup Component used in this example. Create a new MXML File name MyHGroup.mxml and paste the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Create a new MXML File name MyHGroup and add this code -->
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="200" height="20" paddingLeft="10" >

    <fx:Declarations>               
        <!-- The RadioGroup the Buttons will be linked with -->
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="rbGroup"/>          
    </fx:Declarations>

    <!-- Some fancy label -->
    <s:Label id="label" height="20" verticalAlign="middle"/>

    <!-- Your Radio Buttons -->
    <s:RadioButton id="rb1" group="{rbGroup}"/>
    <s:RadioButton id="rb2" group="{rbGroup}"/>
    <s:RadioButton id="rb3" group="{rbGroup}"/>
</s:HGroup>
```